# Angular 5+ multiple http parameters with the same name

Tags: http, post, angular5

I want to have several parameters when I make post request with the same name, exactly the same as here

```
messageId: dc25cffa-5a86-49f0-a6be-207981697eaa
recipientListIds[]: 507e165b-d2d8-430d-b7fa-3cfa6c8c8465
recipientListIds[]: e16e6c0a-2098-4f61-8e31-79e4bb68f8bf
type: {AAD5DC30-CC86-4988-BAF1-98661B02B79B}
```

Comment: So you want to pass that GUID in the list?

Comment: yes. you are right. With square brackets in the name

Answer (score 0):

Might be you are looking for this:

Format the data as expected like:

```
var data = {
  "messageId": "dc25cffa-5a86-49f0-a6be-207981697eaa",
  "recipientListIds": [
    "507e165b-d2d8-430d-b7fa-3cfa6c8c8465",
    "e16e6c0a-2098-4f61-8e31-79e4bb68f8bf"
  ],
"type": "AAD5DC30-CC86-4988-BAF1-98661B02B79B"
}
```

In Service:

Use the `POST` method of `HTTP`:

```
 postData(data): Promise<any>{
    const url = `your_url`;
    return this.http.post(url,data, {headers: your_header})
    .toPromise()
    .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

Comment: sorry,  no. I need format which is described in the question :) I know about solution you've suggested

Comment: Which language you are using for `Backend`?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not able to change current backend. I need that in json, yes

Comment: I am not suggested to do so just wanna know about which language have u used for the backend. is it `C#` , `PHP`

Comment: for example, if I use jquery and try to pass data like this
"recipientListIds": [
    "507e165b-d2d8-430d-b7fa-3cfa6c8c8465",
    "e16e6c0a-2098-4f61-8e31-79e4bb68f8bf"
  ]

it converts this to the needed format for me :) But I don't use jquery in angular app

Comment: Ok can you show your C# code and more how you call normal POST api?

Comment: Becasue I m lot more familiar about C# and angular also so if you provide a proper inforamation then will definatly try to hlp

Comment: Look u have to make it clear to you as the requested format is not a valid JSON. So I would request you collect the proper information from backEnd like `Expected JSON`, `key`

Comment: Because I know the list can be pass like above one (Stated in answer) and can easily consume on server side by using its key Name